# nodejs handling multiple subprocess together

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have got a situation where i need to create n number of subpocess, for each subprocess i need to provide stdin data and expected output, the result of the subpocess is success, if the expected output is same as that of output produced. If all such subprocess is success then the status need to be send to user. How to do the above in nodejs in a nonblocking way?

Answer (score 0):

Promises!

I personally use Bluebird, and here is an example that uses it too.
I hope you understand it, feel free to ask when you do not :-)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var exec   = require('child_process').exec

// Array with input/output pairs
var data = [
  ['input1', 'output1'],
  ['input2', 'output2'],
  ...
]

var PROGRAM = 'cat'

Promise.some(data.map(function(v) {
  var input = v[0]
  var output = v[1]

  new Promise(function(yell, cry) {
    // Yes it is ugly, but exec is just saves many lines here
    exec('echo "' + input + '" | ' + PROGRAM, function(err, stdout) {
      if(err) return cry(err)
      yell(stdout)
    })
  }).then(function(out) {
    if(out !== output) throw new Error('Output did not match!')
  })
}), data.length) // Require them all to succeed
.then(function() {
  // Send succes to user
}).catch(function() {
  // Send failure to the user
})
```

Comment: Im using spawn for creating the new process, inorder to get the output and error stream i use 2 variables and data will be appended to it. The problem is that the data from 1st input set will be their in the string when the 2nd input set is evalauted

Comment: Again, what do you mean?
You have a variable in the global scope that you set? Why?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814680/nodejs-bluebird-promises-how-to-know-if-all-promises-are-executed  Thanks for your help.