# Nodejs Bluebird Promises - How to know if all promises are executed

Tags: javascript, node.js

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679685/nodejs-handling-multiple-subprocess-together/26679996#26679996) answer, the promise has been created, but the method 'then'( also 'done') will be executed without waiting for the output from subprocess, I need to have a method which is to be called after completely executing all subprocess, how this can be accomplished using bluebird api?

#### Sample Code

```js
 var Promise = require('bluebird')
    var exec   = require('child_process').exec

    // Array with input/output pairs
    var data = [
        ['input1', 'output1'],
        ['input2', 'output2'],
        .....
    ]

    var PROGRAM = 'cat'
    Promise.some(data.map(function(v) {
    var input = v[0]
    var output = v[1]

    new Promise(function(yell, cry) {
        exec('echo "' + input + '" | ' + PROGRAM, function(err, stdout) {
            if(err) return cry(err)
                yell(stdout)
            })
        }).then(function(out) {
            if(out !== output) throw new Error('Output did not match!')
        })
    }),data.length)

    .then(function() {
        // Send succes to user if all input-output pair matched
    }).catch(function() {
        // Send failure to the user if any one pair failed to match
    })
```

Here the 'then' function is executed immediately even before the subprocess is completed.

Comment: Please include your specific code so people can understand exactly what you're asking and how to help.  `Promise.all()` is how Bluebird can wait for a group of promises, but you will first have to hook up code to resolve those individual promises at the appropriate time.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry for that,i will update the question.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.some()` expects an array of promises as its first argument.  You are passing the results of `data.map()` to it, but your callback to `data.map()` never returns anything so therefore `.map()` doesn't construct an array of promises and therefore `Promise.some()` has nothing to wait on so it calls it's `.then()` handler immediately.

Also, if you're going to wait for all the promises, then you might as well use `Promise.all()` instead.

This is what I think you want.

Changes:

1. Switch to `Promise.all()` since you want to wait for all the promises.
2. Return the new Promise so `.map()` will create the array of promises.
3. Moved the output check into the original promise so it can reject rather than throw and it just seems like that moves all the result checking into one place.
4. Added all missing semi-colons.
5. Changed `cry` and `yell` to `resolve` and `reject` so code would be more familiar to outsiders expecting normal promise names.

Here's the code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var exec   = require('child_process').exec;

// Array with input/output pairs
var data = [
    ['input1', 'output1'],
    ['input2', 'output2']       
];

var PROGRAM = 'cat';
Promise.all(data.map(function(v) {
    var input = v[0];
    var output = v[1];

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        exec('echo "' + input + '" | ' + PROGRAM, function(err, stdout) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else if (stdout !== output) {
                reject(new Error('Output did not match!'));
            } else {
                resolve(stdout);
            }
        });
    });
})).then(function() {
    // Send succes to user if all input-output pair matched
}).catch(function() {
    // Send failure to the user if any one pair failed to match
});
```